# How to use Numpy .tobytes() to serialize objects

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, serialization

How do you serialized/deserialize a numpy array?

```
A           = np.random.randint(0, 10, 40).reshape(8, 5)
print(A)
print (A.dtype)
snapshot   = A
serialized = snapshot.tobytes()

    [[9 5 5 7 4]
     [3 8 8 1 0]
     [5 7 1 0 2]
     [2 2 7 1 2]
     [2 6 3 5 4]
     [7 5 4 8 3]
     [2 4 2 4 7]
     [3 4 2 6 2]]
    int64
```

Returns

```
 deserialized = np.frombuffer(serialized).astype(np.int64)
 print (deserialized)

 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0]
```

Comment: Use `np.save` (or pickle if you want a string rather than a file).  This the only format that saves shape and dtype information along with the data buffer values.  It can also handle object dtype (with pickling).

Comment: @hpaulj -- what if numpy array is of dtype= 'Object', what is good solution.

Comment: only `np.save` can handle object dtype.  `objects` could be anything `None`, lists, dicts, arrays, Foo class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the default `dtype` used to generate `A` and in `np.frombuffer`. Works as expected when using the correct dtype (may depend on the machine / Python / numpy version):

```
# Python 3.6 64-bits with numpy 1.12.1 64-bits
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, 40).reshape(8, 5)
print(A)
>>> array([[3, 3, 5, 3, 9],
   [1, 4, 7, 1, 8],
   [1, 7, 4, 3, 0],
   [9, 2, 9, 1, 2],
   [2, 8, 9, 1, 1],
   [3, 3, 5, 2, 6],
   [5, 0, 2, 7, 6],
   [2, 8, 8, 0, 7]])
A.dtype
>>> dtype('int32')

deserialized = np.frombuffer(A.tobytes(), dtype=np.int32).reshape(A.shape)
print(deserialized)
>>> array([[3, 3, 5, 3, 9],
   [1, 4, 7, 1, 8],
   [1, 7, 4, 3, 0],
   [9, 2, 9, 1, 2],
   [2, 8, 9, 1, 1],
   [3, 3, 5, 2, 6],
   [5, 0, 2, 7, 6],
   [2, 8, 8, 0, 7]])
```